# Media not found on android 11 while trying to open file using ACTION_VIEW

Tags: java, android, android-11

I have a method that I am using to open file from my application and it is all working fine till android 10 but when I try to open file in android 11 using google photos, it does not open it and shows Media not found toast. I am trying to open in any external app.

Here is my method that I am using:

```
private void openFile(String url) throws IOException {
    // Create URI
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    Intent intent = null;
    // Check what kind of file you are trying to open, by comparing the url with extensions.
    // When the if condition is matched, plugin sets the correct intent (mime) type,
    // so Android knew what application to use to open the file
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    if (url.contains(".doc") || url.contains(".docx")) {
        // Word document
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
    } else if(url.contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    } else if(url.contains(".ppt") || url.contains(".pptx")) {
        // Powerpoint file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    } else if(url.contains(".xls") || url.contains(".xlsx")) {
        // Excel file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    } else if(url.contains(".rtf")) {
        // RTF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
    } else if(url.contains(".wav")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
    } else if(url.contains(".gif")) {
        // GIF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
    } else if(url.contains(".jpg") || url.contains(".jpeg")) {
        // JPG file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    } else if(url.contains(".png")) {
        // PNG file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/png");
    } else if(url.contains(".txt")) {
        // Text file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
    } else if(url.contains(".mpg") || url.contains(".mpeg") || url.contains(".mpe") || url.contains(".mp4") || url.contains(".avi")) {
        // Video files
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
    }

    //if you want you can also define the intent type for any other file

    //additionally use else clause below, to manage other unknown extensions
    //in this case, Android will show all applications installed on the device
    //so you can choose which application to use


    else {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    }

    this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: Please do away with that strictmode stuff.

Comment: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tracer.joblogic/files/401-1604468628817.jpeg" this is the url

Comment: I removed that strict mode stuff but now it is giving me this exception 
'android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tracer.joblogic/files/401-1604468628817.jpeg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()' @blackapps

Comment: Such an url cannot be used for ACTION_VIEW since Android 7/N. Or maybe longer because you used strictmode. Its now really time you remove that strict mode stuff and write decent code.

Comment: Indeed. FileUriExposedException. Solve it! A little googling will give you the solution.

Comment: okay sure thanks, can you give me some idea what kind of url we need to use after 7/N? and thanks for the help

Comment: You can use that kind of url. Who said you could not? You need a different uri.

Comment: I added "androidx.core.content.FileProvider" inside the and it opens that photo in google photos but it keeps showing loader but never the photo
<provider
                  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                  android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
                  android:exported="false"
                  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
      </provider>
@blackapps

Comment: Please put your code in a new code block in your post. We dont like to read code in comments. Do you? Remove that comment.

Answer (score 0):

IDK maybe this is late answer but anyway maybe will help someone :)

The problem is that you need to add permission flags

1. FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
2. FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION

```
val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    this,
    "$packageName.android.fileprovider",
    pngFile
)
Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(photoURI, "image/*")
    flags = FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION                
}.also { 
    startActivity(it) 
}
```